# Making a Model Loader: What to do after reading the vertices and texture?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I recently started a small project within my DirectX 11 engine, which was to make a simple model loader. So far, all it does is open the file with the given file path and prepare to read from it. My question is this, once I read my vertices and texture data, what do I do with it to store it until rendering time? My idea was to put this data in a char array, but this would only work if I only loaded one model, or had many, many char arrays(one for each model).

What I have now is this:

*Read edit!*

In App.cpp:

```
virtual void Load(String^ EntryPoint)
{
    std::auto_ptr<ModelLoad> ml(new ModelLoad);

    if (ml->LoadTVF("Triangle.tvf"))
    {
        // Load vertices and texture into a vertex buffer and texture buffer
    }
    else
    {
        MessageDialog Dialog("Failed to load a game model.\n'Triangle.tvf'", "Error");
        Dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

And in ModelLoader.cpp in class ModelLoad:

```
bool LoadTVF(string FP)
{
    ifstream TVFReader;
    TVFReader.open(FP);
    if (TVFReader.is_open())
    {
        // Read vertices and texture
        TVFReader.close();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I have worked quite a bit more on this and have finished my file reader. Now, I end up with two strings, one for texture path, and one for vertices. I will use those and then...what?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you create Direct3D 11 Vertex Buffers and Index Buffers at load time, and then keep them around until you render. The main reason to keep a memory copy of the original data is for collision, and this is more efficiently done with either bounding volumes or simplified collision meshes that you don't actually render.

See [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) for it's `Model` implementation for some ideas--which is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK)

Note: This is why most games don't fully handle `DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET` or `DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED` coming back from `Present` since in that case you have to destroy the device and recreate all Direct3D objects which would require having the original data. Games usually respond to these by displaying an error and requiring a reload. These are not common errors in properly working applications, so this is usually fine.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, just storing the model data(vertices and texture) into a buffer until rendering. But my question is, how could I do this? Do you know of any semi-simple methods that are safe? Note: For collision detection, I will use invisible meshes.

Comment: See DirectX Tool Kit for an example. It just creates VBs and IBs with the loaded data, throws away the loaded data and just keeps the VBs/IBs

Comment: The `note` is worth the admission fee.

Comment: Is DirectX Tool Kit an addition to DirectX 11? If so, I would prefer not to use it. I like using just the standards.

Comment: DirectX 11 is a raw low-level API. DirectX Tool Kit is reusable sample code. It's all open source, you can use as is, copy & paste parts of it, or just look at it to learn the API and common techniques. The nice thing about DXTK is that you can learn part of the API at a time without having to understand the entire pipeline before you can get a triangle on the screen.