# Directx11 handle device removed

Tags: directx-11

I get the DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED error on some machines. According to this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/handling-device-lost-scenarios) MSDN article this can happen and it should be handled by your application.

I've managed to recreate the device but I'm unsure how to handle all content. It seems I have to create all vertex buffers and textures again, which essentially means I have to reload almost the entire scene. Is this really the correct way?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799677/making-a-model-loader-what-to-do-after-reading-the-vertices-and-texture/29802409#29802409 Chuck's comment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the resources are really gone. You can either:

1. Recreate your GPU device and hot reload everything from storage.
2. Keep CPU memory copies of all GPU resources and reload from these rather than storage.
3. Save application state and restart your whole process as the cleanest option.